# Passing session to a different machine in JSF

Tags: jsf, session, jsf-2

In my JSF application user starts on primary server where the session begins and then the user is redirected to a different server using sendRedirect. I want to pass some authentication token to the next server from primary server. I am trying to set session attribute as:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("auth_token", "1");
```

And then send it to the next server as:

```
response.sendRedirect(encodedUrl);
```

But this attribute is not reaching the new server. I cannot pass this auth_token as request parameter as that wont be secure. So how to get some session data to new server?

Comment: Well that's to be expected isn't it? Unless the servers are within the same cluster, a session object on one server is meaningless to a physically separate server. You should be looking to send that parameter as a GET request parameter, appended to the destination URL

Comment: how about passing the token in the request header? it will not be visible in the url, but will be easily accessible.

Comment: I dont think its possible to pass in request header, as new request and response object are created for sendRedirect. Correct me if I am wrong.